# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter add a last entry and populate it differently

Tags: java, android, firebase

My FirebaseRecyclerAdapter works fine but i now want to add a final entry to give the user the option to add a new user.

I have looked into getItemCount() but that seems to only work with arrays of data allready on the app but the data my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter shows comes straight from the firebase database.

How do i create a last entry and populate it differenlty?

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserRecycler>().setQuery(mDatabase,UserRecycler.class).build();
                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserRecycler, UserViewHolder>(options)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, int position, UserRecycler model)
                    {
                        String name = model.getUserName();
                        holder.userName.setText(name);

                        ImageButton attendee = holder.AttendeeButton;
                        attendee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) { holder.changeAttendence(); }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_recycler_activity,parent,false);

                        return new UserViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: You want the existing last entry to be changed or to add antoher entry as the last entry?

Comment: i would like to add another entry completely different to the rest.

Comment: Is it necessary to be in your adapter, why not to add another separate view?

Comment: i had a look at that as well but was not sure how to set up the views to scroll as if they are one view. if that makes sense?